# cannot make a merge with a branch

Tags: git, github

I have created a new branch. And there I have added code. When I would like to make a merge. I get error:

```
does no point to a commit
```

[image]

Comment: any specific reason why you obfuscated the actual error line in the screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

Your branch isn't named `master/creditos`. It's named `creditos`. So the command is

```
git merge creditos
```

Comment: I would like to combined in the branch master (creditos)

Comment: Yes, so use the command in my answer. `git merge` takes the name of a branch or commit and merges it with the *current* branch, that you have checked out: master.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just want to merge the branch `creditos` back into `master` the command is:

```
git merge creditos
```

When you specify `master/creditos` it is looking for a remote named `master` with a branch `creditos`.